# What is the best use case for an Observable Data Service?

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, rxjs, observable

I've configured my application to use a data service at the root level. Most of the actions in my app take the form of actions on the data model, to which components respond. I'd like to have components subscribe to the data service and respond to the events that it emits, so that they can make changes based on this (i.e., object changes in model, component updates representation of that object). Should I be using an Observable Data Model with rxjs?

Comment: __________ yes.

Answer (score 0):

As Far I had understood from your question above, I think You will Have to Use Observables in your Data Service to get new updates of the changes in the data model. You have to make it a Observable and then "subscribe" to it and listen for new updates

Comment: Cool! That sounds like fun